# How to download files from publicly available google drive URL using Java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have been trying to download files/whole directory from publicly available google drive link URL using Java. I am able to read files which are present in my google drive using google drive libraries but I am not able to understand how to pass google drive link URL.

Also, I tried to use typical method of downloading files from URL  but it produced error java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL.

```
URL url;
URLConnection con;
DataInputStream dis;
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] fileData;
try {
    url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/<some-alphanumeric-code>/<file-name>"); //File Location goes here
    con = url.openConnection(); // open the url connection.
    dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()];
    for (int q = 0; q < fileData.length; q++) {
        fileData[q] = dis.readByte();
    }
    dis.close(); // close the data input stream
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/abhijeetkunwar/file.png")); //FILE Save Location goes here
    fos.write(fileData);  // write out the file we want to save.
    fos.close(); // close the output stream writer
}
catch(Exception m) {
   System.out.println(m);
}
```

Kindly suggest the solution please.

Comment: Can i get a little more context on exactly what you want help with here?    what do you mean by "publicly available google drive link" what is this and how was it created?   Why not download them directly via the drive api?   If you want help fixing "using url.openStream() but it provided the name(without link)"  you need to add the code.

Comment: publicly available google drive link means that if I open the link in browser in incognito mode, it shows the content of the attached folder.

Comment: I am able to use drive APIs to access files in my drive but unable to access the URLs as I am not able to find a method which takes URL as input.

Comment: @DaImTo I have provided the explanations regarding your questions. I request you to have a look and let me know.

Comment: If the link you are talking about is one of those share with me links.   Go to drive right click -> share with me then get that link.   You cant access that with the api as its not a true share its not shared permissions so it wont work.   The drive api will need you to have a permission set.  in order to access it.

Comment: That code looks fun let me give it a go I have never tried with downloading a directory like that interesting use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251026/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-daimto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you are using contains the folder id, the folder should also be readable by everyone.

In this instance you can use the files.list method from the Google drive api and access it using 'folderid' in parents which will return a list of all of the files within that folder.

For this to work the folder needs to be public to viewers which yours seem to be, after our conversation in chat.